# index and base year

Tags: descriptive-statistics, excel

I am creating a league table of a group of people with the aim to track their performance on 5 KPIs using indices. Base month value is set to 100. Out of 5 KPIs, an increase in 3 indices means good performance whereas a drop in other two indices means good performance.

I am thing of aggregating 5 Index number to show overall performance. The issue I am encountering is that I cannot aggregate all 5 indices as they are measured differently. I wanted to know what is the best way to amalgamate the indices so that change in the values is reflected correctly, see attached image:

[image]

I am looking for best logic that can reflect change in indices on aggregated level.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution!

Setting index values of two KPIs to inverse of their current value solved the issue. For example, (KPI4 month Feb) value is 52 change it to 148 means the change is still 52 points.